# When to use the promise returned by ractive.set?

Tags: ractivejs

The ractive.set method returns a promise. When performing a *simple* set operation (single value or map) and then immediately referencing the new value via ractive.get, is it recommended to use the promise? Or is that completely unnecessary?

I've been avoiding the promise and found that I don't need it, but maybe I've just been lucky so far. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
ractive.set("foo", "bar");
console.log(ractive.get("foo"));   // always outputs the correct value "bar"
```

I'm worried that the set operation is asynchronous and this will become evident on slower machines or if I start using the more advanced features of Ractive.

According to the [Ractive docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-set):

> [ractive.set] Returns a Promise that **will be called after the set
>   operation and any transitions are complete**.

Based on that, I wonder if the promise is really meant for post-transition work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Based on that, I wonder if the promise is really meant for
>   post-transition work.

Exactly. The value update (and the resulting DOM changes per the template) happen ***synchronously***, the promise is meant for asynchronous response to end of transitions.

This is also why the `set` operation also has a hash map option for the input parameters so multiple sets will be batched in one go:

```
ractive.set({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
}).then( () => {
   // this happens asynchronously ***after*** code execution has
   // continued below on next event cycle or after transitions complete 
});

// data and DOM have been updated as the code continues synchronously here:
console.log( ractive.get() );
```